# Old zombie movie I saw in the early 90's where a girl crawls through the duct vents of the apt building to escape them

Tags: story-identification, movie, zombie

It was a movie that took place in I think an apartment complex. There was a little girl who got attacked in her apartment and she had to escape by crawling from room to room through the duct vents. The building had a large parking garage that the surviving people holed up in from the zombies.

*Spoiler*.

> The zombies broke in and killed everyone at the end and the little girl was trapped in a car surrounded by them. I think the movie was in black and white, but not positive.